# SystemVerilog stringify (`") operator and line breaks

Tags: system-verilog, active-hdl

I'm using the SystemVerilog stringify operator, `` `" ``, in a macro, as below. The case is deliberately contrived to show the bug:

```
module my_test();
    `define print(x) $fwrite(log_file, `"x`")
    `define println(x) $fwrite(log_file, `"x\n`")
    integer log_file;

    initial begin
        log_file = $fopen("result.txt", "w");
        `print(A);
        `print(B);
        `println(C);
        `println(D);
        `print(E);
        `print(F);
    end
endmodule
```

This gives the output (no trailing newline):

```
ABC
`D
`EF
```

Why are there `` ` ``s in the output, but only from the `println`?
Is this documented behaviour in the spec, or a bug in my simulator (Aldec Active-HDL)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in your tool. However, the second `` `" ``  is not needed and gives you the results you are looking for.

Comment: Can you link me to an explanation of why that second `` `" `` is unnecessary? Preferably a page in the spec

Comment: There is only one page in the 1315 pages of the LRM that mentions `" and it mentions mixing.

Comment: I'm a little shocked how vague that description is - it says that the macro text can use a mixture, not specifically that a string literal can begin with one and end with the other.

Comment: It does go out of its way to say that if you start with the un-escaped double quote, the final quote could never be escaped because the back-tick would be considered part of the string literal and not an escape charactor. So the only mixture allowed is starting with an escaped-"  and ending with a simple ".

Comment: That's possibly not restrictive enough. It might just mean that ```define macro {`"foo`", "bar"}`` is allowed. That's a mixture too.